# Custom metric based on tensorflow's streaming metrics returns NaN

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to define the F1-score as a custom metric in TensorFlow for a `DNNClassifier`. To do that, I wrote a function

```
def metric_fn(predictions=[], labels=[], weights=[]):
    P, _ = tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_precision(predictions, labels)
    R, _ = tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_recall(predictions, labels)
    if P + R == 0:
        return 0
    return 2*(P*R)/(P+R)
```

that uses `streaming_precision` and `streaming_recall` from TensorFlow to calulate the F1 score. After that I made a new entry to the validation_metrics:

```
validation_metrics = {
    "accuracy":
        tf.contrib.learn.MetricSpec(
            metric_fn=tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_accuracy,
            prediction_key=tf.contrib.learn.PredictionKey.CLASSES),
    "precision":
        tf.contrib.learn.MetricSpec(
            metric_fn=tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_precision,
            prediction_key=tf.contrib.learn.PredictionKey.CLASSES),
    "recall":
        tf.contrib.learn.MetricSpec(
            metric_fn=tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_recall,
            prediction_key=tf.contrib.learn.PredictionKey.CLASSES),
    "f1score":
        tf.contrib.learn.MetricSpec(
            metric_fn=metric_fn,
            prediction_key=tf.contrib.learn.PredictionKey.CLASSES)
}
```

However, although I get correct precision and recall values, `f1score` is always `nan`:

```
INFO:tensorflow:Saving dict for global step 151: accuracy = 0.982456, accuracy/baseline_label_mean = 0.397661, accuracy/threshold_0.500000_mean = 0.982456, auc = 0.982867, f1score = nan, global_step = 151, labels/actual_label_mean = 0.397661, labels/prediction_mean = 0.406118, loss = 0.310612, precision = 0.971014, precision/positive_threshold_0.500000_mean = 0.971014, recall = 0.985294, recall/positive_threshold_0.500000_mean = 0.985294
```

Something is wrong with my `metric_fn`, but I can't figure it out. 
The values `P` and `R` obtained by `metric_fn` are of the form
`Tensor("precision/value:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)`. I find this a bit strange. I was expecting a scalar tensor.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the problem may come from the fact that the streaming metrics you use within your `metric_fn` do not get any update.

Try the following (I also included minor modifications to my taste):

```
def metric_fn(predictions=None, labels=None, weights=None):
    P, update_op1 = tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_precision(predictions, labels)
    R, update_op2 = tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_recall(predictions, labels)
    eps = 1e-5;
    return (2*(P*R)/(P+R+eps), tf.group(update_op1, update_op2))
```

Comment: That works, thank you. However, there is a little syntax error (missing ``)`` in the first part of the return statement).

Answer (score 2):

[`tf.learn.MetricSpec`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/MetricSpec) `__init__` first argument is `metric_fn`.

The documentation says:

> metric_fn: A function to use as a metric. See _adapt_metric_fn for rules on how predictions, labels, and weights are passed to this function. This must return either a single Tensor, which is interpreted as a value of this metric, or a pair (value_op, update_op), where value_op is the op to call to obtain the value of the metric, and update_op should be run for each batch to update internal state.

Since you want to use streaming operations in your `metric_fn`, you can't return a single Tensor but you have to take into account that the streaming operations have an inner state that has to be updated.

Thus, the first part of your `metric_fn` should be:

```
def metric_fn(predictions=[], labels=[], weights=[]):
    P, update_precision = tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_precision(predictions, labels)
    R, update_recall = tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_recall(predictions, labels)
```

Then, if you want to return `0` when a condition is met you can't use python `if` statement (that's not computed insede the tensorflow graph) but you have to use [`tf.cond`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/cond) (computation inside the graph).

Moreover, you want to check the value of `P` and `R` only **after** the update operation (otherwise the first value is undefined or `nan`).

To force the evaluation of `tf.cond` after the `P` and `R` update, you can use [`tf.control_dependencies`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/control_dependencies)

```
def metric_fn(predictions=[], labels=[], weights=[]):
    P, update_precision = tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_precision(predictions, labels)
    R, update_recall = tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_recall(predictions, labels)

    with tf.control_dependencies([P, update_precision, R, update_recall]):
        score = tf.cond(tf.equal(P + R, 0.), lambda: 0, lambda: 2*(P*R)/(P+R))
    return score, tf.group(update_precision, update_recall)
```

Comment: You don't need the `control_dependencies`, because this is already taken care of within the streaming metrics. So in the end it boils down to my answer.