# Why does my custom streaming metric always give different results when run on the same inputs?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to learn how to create my own custom streaming metric in Tensorflow.

I've started by trying to code my own function to compute the f1-score.

Here's what I have so far:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_fscore_support, f1_score, precision_score

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

# Custom streaming metric to compute f1 score.
# Code is from answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44764688/custom-metric-based-on-tensorflows-streaming-metrics-returns-nan/44935895
def metric_fn(predictions=None, labels=None, weights=None):
    P, update_op1 = tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_precision(predictions, labels)
    R, update_op2 = tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_recall(predictions, labels)
    eps = 1e-5;
    return (2*(P*R)/(P+R+eps), tf.group(update_op1, update_op2))


# True labels
labels = np.array([1, 0, 0, 1])
# Predicted labels
preds = np.array([1, 1, 0, 1])

f1 = metric_fn(preds, labels)

init1 = tf.global_variables_initializer()
init2 = tf.local_variables_initializer()
sess.run([init1, init2])

# Check result with output from sklearn
print(f1_score(labels, preds))

# Run a custom metric a few times
print(sess.run(f1))
print(sess.run(f1))
print(sess.run(f1))
```

This is the output I get:

```
0.8
(0.0, None)
(0.99999624, None)
(0.79999518, None)
```

The first line is the f1 score computed using sklearn's f1_score function, which is correct. The rest are from `metric_fn`.

I do not understand the output from `metric_fn`. Why does the result from `metric_fn` always change even though I give it the same output? Also, none of its results are correct, even though the formula I coded is correct. What is going on and what changes do i need to make to get the correct result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can separate the output of `metric_fn` into two parts in this way:

```
f1_value, update_op = metric_fn(preds, labels)
```

where `f1_value` is the current value of your score & `update_op` is the op which takes the new values of preds and labels and update the f1 score.

So, in this context, you could change your code in this way:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_fscore_support, f1_score, precision_score

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

# Custom streaming metric to compute f1 score.
# Code is from answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44764688/custom-metric-based-on-tensorflows-streaming-metrics-returns-nan/44935895
def metric_fn(predictions=None, labels=None, weights=None):
    P, update_op1 = tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_precision(predictions, labels)
    R, update_op2 = tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_recall(predictions, labels)
    eps = 1e-5;
    return (2*(P*R)/(P+R+eps), tf.group(update_op1, update_op2))


# True labels
labels = np.array([1, 0, 0, 1])
# Predicted labels
preds = np.array([1, 1, 0, 1])

f1_value, update_op = metric_fn(preds, labels)

init1 = tf.global_variables_initializer()
init2 = tf.local_variables_initializer()
sess.run([init1, init2])

# Check result with output from sklearn
print(f1_score(labels, preds))

# Run a custom metric a few times
print(sess.run(f1_value))
print(sess.run(update_op))
print(sess.run(f1_value))
```

And you get, as expected:

```
0.8 # Obtained with sklearn
0.0 # Value of f1_value before calling update_op
None # update_op does not return anything
0.799995 # Value of f1_value after calling update_op
```

Note that `update_op` returns `None` solely because an op created with `tf.group` has no output. Each `update_op1` and `update_op2` would have returned respectively 1.0 and 0.6666667.